# How can a singleton Java EE bean obtain a reference to itself?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1, java-ee-7

I have a singleton bean for which the `@PostConstruct` method needs to call an `@Asynchronous` method within itself. It cannot do so directly using `this` because that makes the call synchronous. I cannot `@Inject` itself because it is circular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use such type of wrapper:

```
@Singleton
public class SingletonBean {



@Stateless
public static class AsynchronousMethodLauncher{
    @EJB
    private SingletonBean singletonBean;

    public void launch(){
        singletonBean.asynchronousMethod();
    }
}

    @EJB
    AsynchronousMethodLauncher launcher;

    @Asynchronous
    public void asynchronousMethod(){
        //Place your code here
    }

    public void yourMethod(){
        launcher.launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: good suggestion! (if a better answer is posted i will accept it)

Comment: the other answer is better, you should accept it ;)

Comment: Well, Wildfly complains about the inner class `Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEJB0128: EJB AsynchronousMethodLauncher of type com.acme.job.JobScheduler$AsynchronousMethodLauncher must not be inner class`

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest natural Java EE way:

```
@Singleton
public class AsyncSingletonBeanBean {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        AsyncSingletonBeanBean myBean = sessionContext.getBusinessObject(this.getClass());
        myBean.foo();
    }

    @Asynchronous
    public Future<String> foo() {
        return new AsyncResult<String>("Hello");
    }
}
```